# JS/TS/Angular2 - Replace characters while writing in Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using TS/Angular2 for my app. 
I have a textbox with a text of a certain(important) length, and to be able to control its length, I want to replace the next character with the one typed.

So, if I've got a text "test" and the courser position is "t | est". 
If the user types a new character, I want the "e" to be replaced with that character.

So If I type "a" at this position,  the result should be "tast" instead of "test", if you know what I mean.

I couldn't find anything about this (which might be due to my disability to find the correct expression for  this). 
Is there a way to set something like the "writingmode" or whatever it's called directly in the code or do I have to code this manually?

Thanks!

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/terqr0ch/4/ ? Sorry it isn't Angular2

Comment: Yep, in that way and then for every character. So that in the end the length is the same as before. So there is no option for that, is it?

Comment: In my sample end length is the same, I'm replacing characters, but this will work just once per word, because before I replace character I'm checking if selected word is in my dictionary, to have that behavior just for specific words.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Seems as if I really need to code this, if there's not an option for html-inputs for that. Well, okay. Thanks to you. I need this to happen for everything typed in, for every character (including spaces) inside of my textarea everytime something gets typed.